# how to filter table based on multiple columns automatically upon refresh without losing text in input boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm currently using multifilter (a jquery plugin at https://tommyp.github.io/multifilter/) in my code. if you take a look at that link it shows you how it filters the table in realtime. my problem is that whatever text i enter into the input boxes are lost when i refresh the page. i figured out that if i set the input to autocomplete=on, like so:

```
<input autocomplete='on' class='filter' name='name' placeholder='name' data-col='name'/>
```

it will retain the values in the input boxes. however, it does not trigger the multifilter.js upon refresh requiring me to still type something into the input boxes.

how would i trigger the plugin upon refresh so that the table will automatically filter results based on whatever text was in the input boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use `autocomplete` for this, since autocomplete is a feature that is used for something different ([w3schools autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)):

> Autocomplete allows the browser to predict the value. When a user starts to type in a field, the browser should display options to fill in the field, based on earlier typed values.

A good solution to solving your problem is [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage).

The following code is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var name = localStorage.getItem('name') || '';

    $("#name").val(name);
    $('.filter').multifilter(); // for filtering values in the table

    $('#name').keyup(function(e) {
        var name = $(this).val();

        localStorage.setItem('name', name);
    });
});
```

The above code uses the `localStorage` API to get a value that has already been set with a call to `localStorage.setItem()` and sets the value of the `input` equal to the value retrieved from the `getItem()` call. The code then checks everytime the user types something into the `input` and saves the value for later retrieval using `localStorage.setItem()`.

This way, the value is persistent and each time the user refreshes the page, because the value is stored using `localStorage`, it loads the value into the `input` using `localStorage` (note that you do need to have 3rd party cookies enabled to use `lcoalStorage`).